# lambda to delete indices older than x days on elastic-search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

lambda to delete indices older than x days on elastic-search

I used this script

```
import boto3
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth    
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection    
import curator     
host = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com' 
region = 'us-east-1'    
service = 'es'    
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()    
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

def lambda_handler(event, context):        
es = Elasticsearch(    
hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],    
http_auth = awsauth,    
use_ssl = True,   
verify_certs = True,    
connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection    
)    
 
index_list = curator.IndexList(es)
index_list.filter_by_age(source='creation_date', direction='older', timestring='%Y-%m-%d', unit='days', unit_count=7)    
 
print("Found %s indices to delete" % len(index_list.indices))    
 
if index_list.indices:    
curator.DeleteIndices(index_list).do_action()    
 
print('Indices deleted successfully')
```

when i run this script Attribute error is shown.

How to resolve this??

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "curator_03.py", line 10, in <module>    
    awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)    
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'access_key'
```

Comment: how to resolve this...??

Comment: See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361965/check-whether-aws-credentials-are-present-without-making-any-requests)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please edit the code with the right format (either using the "{}" from the edit field or starting each line with 4 blanks)? This helps to improve readability. The current code snipped will not run properly because of non existing intendation. Thank you.

Comment: Sure @Raubsauger